# Equality in the proof of the theorem " every continuous function is integrable"

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

[image]

This is the beginning part of the proof of the theorem that every continuous function is integrable. What is confusing me here is the equality sign in the last expression. Is there a mistake or an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)-f(y)<\frac\epsilon{2(b-a)}$ for $x,y\in D$ implies $\sup_D f-\inf_D f\le \frac\epsilon{2(b-a)}$, but in general it does not imply $\sup_D f-\inf_D f< \frac\epsilon{2(b-a)}$.

Comment: can you please explain why?

Comment: @AyanShah: Suppose in general that set $A$ of real numbers is non empty and bounded above. And let $x < K$ for every $x \in A$ where $K$ is some upper bound. Then it does not mean that $\sup A < K$. we may have $\sup A = K$ also. Note that $\sup A$ is also an upper bound of $A$ and it may belong to $A$ (which leads to equality) or it may not belong to $A$ (which leads to inequality).